# Get combo-box (list-item-pairs) both selected-text and value in Progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Can I have both the "selection text" and "value" of a combo-box?

Example : 
A combo-box named cb has this values (List-Item-Pairs selected)

```
text1,1,
text2,2,
text3,3
```

When I select **text1** I want to get both **text1** and **1** . I have the value (1 in this situation) but I couldn't get text1.

I've tried value, selection-text, input-value but It doesn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
MESSAGE 
   ENTRY(LOOKUP(SELF:SCREEN-VALUE, SELF:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS),     SELF:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS)    
   ENTRY(LOOKUP(SELF:SCREEN-VALUE, SELF:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS) - 1, SELF:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS)
  VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTON OK.
```